# How to convert PHP array into Yaml?

Tags: php, yaml

How to convert PHP array into Yaml?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using [yaml_emit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.yaml-emit.php) or [yaml_parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.yaml-parse.php)

Check [this link](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-yaml-in-php-projects/). It is having good explanation of using YAML in Your PHP Projects

Answer (score 10):

You use [Yaml PECL package](http://php.net/manual/en/book.yaml.php), but this may not always be possible (e.g on shared hosting) since it's not bundled with PHP by default.

Other solution may be to use some PHP library like [Symfony's Yaml Component](https://github.com/symfony/yaml)